# Separate column based on condition in same table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having a result set from a table in which I have to split a specific value and display in another column(user defined) based on a condition.

//Query

```
    SELECT wtcCommentId, wtcTransactionId, wtcTaskId,  wtcUserLogin,
     wtcCommentDateTime, wtcCommentText
    FROM   dbo.tblWorkflowTransactionComments (NOLOCK)
    WHERE  wtcTransactionId = 141248
```

The output for the above query will be some 10 rows.

In the above query I need to separate the `wtcCommentText` column if the `wtcTaskId` for that result is 0. So if the `wtcTaskId` is 0 the `wtcCommenttext` value should be displayed in a separate column(transcommenttext) and for others it should be displaying in the same column(`wtcCommentText`). So that I can make a split between the comments based on the `taskId`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it really makes sense, but okay, I'm game for a laugh:

```
SELECT wtcCommentId, wtcTransactionId, wtcTaskId,  wtcUserLogin,
 wtcCommentDateTime,
 CASE WHEN wtcTaskId!=0 THEN wtcCommentText END as wtcCommentText,
 CASE WHEN wtcTaskId=0 THEN wtcCommentText END as transcommenttext
FROM   dbo.tblWorkflowTransactionComments (NOLOCK)
WHERE  wtcTransactionId = 141248
```

It seems like the kind of trivial reformatting that would be better done in a front end or report generator though.